# How so I SSH to two different machines with the same IP?

Tags: ssh, vpn, private-ip

I have two similar deployments of a web app, each on separate virtual network with private IP addresses. Both have a VM at 10.0.4.4.

I can VPN from my development machine into either network and SSH onto the VMs however when I switch networks SSH kicks up a fuss about the hosts having different keys.

Can I configure multiple key signatures against a single hostname to avoid this? What is the recommended way to connect to different machines which have the same IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH checks its `known_hosts` for all entries for this host. If *all* of them don't match, including the usual case of *all* being *the single one entry*, then SSH will complain.

If *any* of them matches SSH succeeds at host checking.

From [`man sshd`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd.8#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT) in SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT:

> When performing host authentication, **authentication is accepted if any
> matching line has the proper key**; either one that matches exactly or,
> if the server has presented a certificate for authentication, the key
> of the certification authority that signed the certificate.

[...]

> **It is permissible (but not recommended) to have several lines or
> different host keys for the same names**. This will inevitably happen
> when short forms of host names from different domains are put in the
> file. It is possible that the files contain conflicting information;
> authentication is accepted if valid information can be found from
> either file.

One (less un)common usage of this is for SSH servers often used as SFTP servers in high-availability context through a VIP: when there's a failover from one node to the other, the host authentication can change.

One can use `ssh-keyscan 10.0.4.4` possibly with additional options (such as option `-H` for hashing privacy) twice: once on each different VM, to retrieve all possible host keys and append them or some of them to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Then no authentication error will happen anymore, until trying to access a 3rd unrelated node with the same address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't identify the OS of the development machine but this should work for openSSH on either Linux or Mac.

From the command line

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 10.0.4.4
```

Or set up ~/.ssh/config with the lines

```
Host 10.0.4.4
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

If you control the VMs and they are Linux, you can copy all of the key files in `/etc/ssh/` from one VM to the other and then restart `sshd`. This will give identical host keys.